# Is there a way to build/connect mutually exclusive power outlets?

Tags: receptacle

I have a circuit that gets overloaded if the kettle and the convection oven are both connected
There is no way to upgrade the circuit and we often forget not to connect the two to the same double power outlet

Is there a way to make the two outlets active just one at a time ? I would like them to become mutually exclusive when active

This is for US/Canada

Udpate:

Here is a the wiring diagram copied from the below selected answer

[image]

Comment: Where on the planet are you?

Comment: The best way to do what you want to do is to plug them both into a **single, one-gang** power outlet. Only one appliance can be plugged in at once. However, that may not be the best answer to the problem.

Comment: Cheapest way would be to use one of those child safe outlet covers on one outlet of the double.  To use both will need to upgrade the circuit.

Comment: It may be easier to add an additional circuit. Upgrading the circuit would require replacing the wire that is likely near impossible without tearing up the wall. Fishing a new circuit may be easier depending on the route and will be a lot more useful.

Comment: Close. But that's a 4-way.

Comment: Both 'connected' or both 'running'?  If the issue is both connected and not running, I would think there is some other issue as they shouldn't be drawing much power in the off state.  Even one off and one on should be ok.

Comment: @rtaft AIUI, the issue is that both are connected all the time but users are not consistently able to make sure to only turn on one of the devices at a time. Hence a switch to force that.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact. The question could be interpreted as unplugging when not in use, which is why I ask to make sure.  The alternative is that something is using a lot more juice than it should be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you (a) can't realistically add a new circuit and (b) the low-tech solutions don't work for you (e.g., a single receptacle instead of a duplex receptacle), there is a solution - a **3-way switch**.

A 3-way switch has a common wire (hot or switched hot) on one side and two *travellers* on the other side. If you connect one traveller to the top hot screw of a duplex receptacle and the other traveller to the bottom hot screw of a duplex receptacle **and remove the tab on the hot side of the receptacle** then you now have a switch that makes the top or bottom work, but never both at the same time.

You will likely need a larger junction box, but other than that this is really quite simple. There is, however, one additional concern. A 20A circuit must have at least two 15A receptacles *or* at least one 20A receptacle. So if this is a 20A circuit (required for kitchen countertop receptacles, but older circuits are grandfathered, so you may have a 15A circuit) *and* this duplex receptacle is the *only* receptacle on the circuit *and* this is a duplex 15A rather than a duplex 20A, then you will be violating the spirit of the law, and possibly the letter of the law. If that's the case, the solution is to replace the 15A duplex with a 20A duplex, so that each single receptacle *by itself* satisfies the requirements for a 20A circuit.

If this is a 20A circuit, you should use a 20A-rated switch. Those are a little more expensive as 15A switches are more than enough for normal lighting loads, but 20A aren't hard to find.

The last piece, which may be a deal-breaker, is GFCI. Kitchen countertop receptacles must be GFCI protected, and that is an upgrade worth doing, in general, even if you are not making other changes. However, a GFCI duplex receptacle does not normally have the removal tab to split the receptacle (for MWBC, half-switched or your particular idea), and replacing GFCI with standard is definitely a "no" unless you can install the GFCI elsewhere to protect this receptacle.

The house I grew up in had two dishwashers with a switch like this (except I didn't understand it at the time) for the hardwired dishwashers - just installed sideways and "flip it towards the dishwasher you want to use", but receptacles are really no different. The switch was actually to prevent overloading the plumbing, which was the real limiting factor in that particular situation.

[image: switch with ground]

Note that the travellers are not necessarily the top 2 screws. They could be both on the left or both on the right, depending on make/model. The instructions should make it clear, but normal practice is that the travellers are the same color and the common is a different color - e.g., brass for travellers and black for common, or brass for travellers, silver for common, etc.

The travellers don't have to be red and blue - for a side-by-side switch/receptacle you can just pull some black wire from a piece of NM cable and use black for both. You just can't use white or green.

Comment: That sounds doable. Is there a diagram for this? I am not sure if you are recommending a three way switch that contols an outlet or the outlet will work like a three way switch, I am not fully familiar with the terminolgy you are using here, English is my second language,  so when it comes to domain terminology I need some time to get the vocabulary and I have not worked with the Electricals that much

Comment: Normally a 3-way switch is paired with another 3-way switch. I am suggesting a 3-way switch paired with the top/bottom of a duplex receptacle.

Comment: yes that is what I meant but I still need to see a wiring diagram. I think this is doable especially if I find a nice elegant switch

Comment: Technically, split-wired 15A kitchen countertop receptacles aren’t “grandfathered”, they are valid code for new builds. You can continue to wire kitchen counter receptacles in that fashion.

Comment: @RibaldEddie The "grandfathered" part is doing that on a 15A circuit rather than a 20A circuit.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact “grandfathered” as a term in bylaws and regulations means that you can’t do it that way any more but if you do have it done that way, it’s fine. If you go to make alterations, you DO have to bring it up to code. That’s not the case here — 15A split receptacles are valid for kitchen countertops. Now and before. New and old. 20A non-split receptacles are a newer addition to the code. Nothing was deprecated so there is no “grandfathered” rule.

Comment: @RibaldEddie Can you install a brand-new 15A **circuit** with 15A split receptacles as a kitchen countertop circuit? I don't think so. Can you install a brand-new 20A circuit with 15A split receptacles - yes. If you have an existing 15A circuit with 15A split receptacles can you keep using it - yes.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I suppose that there could be a difference in Canada vs the US (where I assume you're located) but I am looking at the code book right now and it's pretty clear that in the Canadian code, you can still wire a kitchen in that fashion.

Comment: @RibaldEddie It is certainly possible that Canada differs on this. In a quick search, it looks like this is NEC 210.52 but I find it all over the place - **Kitchen needs at least 2 20A circuits, which can have 15A or 20A receptacles**. Apparently this has been code (to some degree) since 1959. The problem is *not* 15A receptacles - that's fine. It isn't 15A *split* receptacles - that's fine. It is that the circuits (for new installs - old is grandfathered) are supposed to be 20A, not 15A.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact there’s nothing like that in the Canadian code. It just says receptacles can be 15A split or 20A. In the section on branch circuits for residential dwellings it just reiterates the 15A split or 20A dedicated branches for kitchen counter receptacles.

Comment: @RibaldEddie This may indeed be a difference between NEC and CEC. According to https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/ontario-canada-new-counter-receptacle-wiring-question.619313/ the countertop circuits can be *either* 15A split or 20A regular. 15A split being MWBC so really 30A total, which (more than) satisfies the spirit of the "20A circuit using 15A receptacles" NEC rule - i.e., to make sure you can get more than 15A out of the circuit.

Comment: Hi guys
   I added a diagram with my understanding of the wiring for this, did I get it right ?  https://i.imgur.com/oa3Vjhw.png

Answer (score 5):

### You don't need gadgets, just awareness

The problem isn't the appliances being *connected*. Appliances don't use power merely from being plugged in.

To use power, the appliance must be *turned on*.

**So don't turn them both on at once.**

You don't need a "nanny device" to protect you from yourself.  You just need to know the actual facts in force here.

1500W (12 amps) is a [popular size](https://youtu.be/V-jmSjy2ArM?t=33) for heat-making kitchen appliances.  All kitchen circuits are 15 or 20A.  Obviously you can't run two of *anything* at once.

My sweetie and I deal with that every morning from fall to spring.  My sweetie is running the space heater on high (12 amps), so I have to turn it off (or down to low, 7 A) so I can run the toaster (7 A).   Not rocket science here, just keep decently below our breaker trip of 20 (there are about 4A of small loads on the circuit).

Here, let an electrical professional explain it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGPMadwqPKQ